# Cloud firestore function that duplicate data

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I know that normally we have to provide something but actually I'm quit lost about function in firebase, I try to do a function that every month, it's get data from a field in a firebase document, and with that create a new document with the user id and the data in an other table. Is that possible, someone know how to achieve and understand ?

```
 export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  try {
    db.collection('users').get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot: any[]) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            const user = doc.id;
            const conso = doc.data().conso_co2;
            db.doc("historic"+user).add({
                    consommation: conso,
                    date: new Date()
                })

        });
    })
    .catch(function(error: any) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
  }catch(error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
  }
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

I put a Http trigger to simplify the debugging

Answer (score 0):

I believe a modification of this should accomplish what you're trying to get done - if not let me know in the comments and I can work with you on it.

Your modified version of this method should allow you to

1. Run at midnight the first day of the month
2. Get data from a given document
3. Use that data to create another document somewhere else

```
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("0 0 1 * *")
    .timeZone("Europe/Paris")
    .onRun(context => {
        try {
            const sfDoc = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");
            const doc = await sfDoc.get();
            if (doc.exists) {
                const data = doc.data()
                const laDoc = db.collection("cities").doc("LA");
                await laDoc.set({
                    name: "Los Angeles",
                    state: "CA",
                    country: "USA",
                    newData: data
                })
            }
        }  
        catch(error) {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);

        }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you it helped me, the fact is now i need to retrieve a specific field from all my user,the fact is We achieve to get all users data but I don't know how to get the specifique field

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following - if you have the whole user object you should have access to all its properties.

Comment: You are probably true, but actually I don't know how to get it :( , I get something like { obj_euro: '20000',
  eco_co2: '15359.4',
  kilometre: '256.0',
  conso_co2: '4526.2',
  obj_co2: '5557' } but i want just one field

Comment: So let's say you have your object, I'll call it `data`. And data looks like `{ obj_euro: '20000', eco_co2: '15359.4', kilometre: '256.0', conso_co2: '4526.2', obj_co2: '5557' }`, I can access any of those properties like so: `data.kilometre` for plain access `const kilometre = data.kilometre` to store what you want in a variable, (or even cleaner using ES6 destructuring) `const { kilometre } = data`

Comment: I try like : doc.data().conso_co2 but nothing :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212818/discussion-between-beatles-bob-and-coloradocolby).